# CSV Dict writer formatting

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a problem formatting my files. I want each header to be associated with its corresponding value. I also need to access each value(index) specifically for data conversions.

```
class CsvReader:

read_path = './data/samples.dat'
with open(read_path, newline='') as File, open('./data/samples_curated.csv', 'w+') as write_path:
    reader = csv.reader(File, delimiter="|")

    for row in reader:
        next(File)

        write_path.write('\n')
        fnames = ['Sequence n', 'Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second', 'Speed', 'Acc Foward',
                  'Acc Backward', 'Acc left', 'Acc right', 'Acc up', 'Acc down', 'E/W Cord', 'E/W',
                  'N/S Cord', 'N/S', 'Engine RMP', 'Voltage', 'Altitude Above sea Level', 'Driver ID 1',
                  'Driver ID 2', 'Driver ID 3', 'Driver ID 4', 'Binary Digital Input', 'Engine Temprature'
                  ]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(write_path, fieldnames=fnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'Sequence n': row, 'Year': row})
```

Comment: Start by defining your `csv.writer()`, together with the header, outside of the `for row in reader:` loop.

Comment: Yes thank you for the help, but i also need each header to match column within the row and and also access each row value individually to convert things like dates.

Comment: Read about [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and replace `csv.reader(...` with `csv.DictReader(fieldnames=fnames...`. Remove **all** lines with `writer....`.